# Why is the calculation of 1000 factorial so fast in Lisp (and shows correct result)?

Tags: c++, performance, lisp, common-lisp, factorial

I have tried to implement naive calculation of the factorial in Lisp.

```
(defun factorial (n)
  (if (equal n 1)
    1
    (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))
```

The code works for small numbers (< 10) as one would expect. However, I have been very surprised it also works for much higher numbers (e.g 1000) and the result is calculated almost instantly.

On the other hand, in C++ the following code retrieves 0 for `factorial(1000)`.

```
long long unsigned factorial(int n)
{
    if(n == 1) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

Why is the calculation in Lisp so fast and how is the number stored in memory?

Comment: What Lisp are you using? Some don't compile everything by default; it might be a bit faster still if you compile that individual function with `(compile 'factorial)`.

Comment: Fun fact: Bignums first appeared in one of the ancestors of Common Lisp in 1973.

Comment: @Kaz I use Clisp 2.49.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common Lisp has [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) and tries to use them when necessary (and unless told otherwise) so that results are mathematically useful for most users: non-computing people usually do not expect modulo arithmetics over powers of 2.

You could have a look at how bignums are implemented (e.g. [sbcl](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/src/code/bignum.lisp)) to better understand how they work, how memory is allocated, and why they are fast. There is a lot of work behind bignums to make them fast in practice (the only problem I ever had with bignums is *printing* them (especially in Emacs)).

The `long long unsigned` type should be at least 64bits wide (in C++ the width is always a power of 2, but I am not sure the standard requires it), and unsigned integers are defined to have a wrap-around semantics. You obtain 0 because the factorial is a multiple of 2<sup>64</sup>

```
(mod (factorial 1000) (expt 2 64))
0
```

In fact, [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)
 can be used to determine the highest exponent `v` such that 2<sup>v</sup> divides 1000!:

```
CL-USER> (loop
            with p = 2
            with n = 1000
            for i from 1
            for v = (floor n (expt p i))
            while (plusp v)
              sum v)
994
```

We can confirm that `(expt 2 994)` does divides that big number:

```
CL-USER> (mod (factorial 1000) (expt 2 994))
0
```

But `(expt 2 995)` does not:

```
CL-USER> (mod (factorial 1000) (expt 2 995))
167423219872854268898191413915625282900219501828989626163085998182867351738271269139562246689952477832436667643367679191435491450889424069312259024604665231311477621481628609147204290704099549091843034096141351171618467832303105743111961624157454108040174944963852221369694216119572256044331338563584
```

Answer (score 1):

Common Lisp imposes (theoretically) no bounds to integers (like Python for example). The storage of an integer is automatically allocated as necessary to represent large integers.
On the other side, C++ native integers (eg. int types) are stored in a fixed-size amount of memory. The size is usually between 1 and 8 bytes on most today platforms.

The benefit of the C++ approach is that integer computations can be very quickly since they can be directly compiled to very fast processor instructions (unlike Common Lisp).
However, the downside is that when a computed value is too big to fit in a C++ native integer-typed variable, an overflow occurs. The resulting value is not mathematically correct anymore.

Since `factorial(1000)` is a very big number, it generally does not fit in a native integer. Overflows are the reason why get 0. You can get mathematically correct results using a (non-standard) high-level variable-sized C++ integer type such as the one proposed in the [Boost multi-precision library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html).
Using this, the computation of `factorial(1000)` can also be done very quickly in C++ (and still be mathematically correct).

Comment: you would need to tell a Common Lisp compiler via declarations to use unchecked and overflowing integers.